# Should the book example be refined to avoid inconsistent results

Tags: alloy

When existing Alloy models of the book example are used in Alloy 6.1,
the evaluation results give contr-intuitive representation of add operation:
[image: analysis results]

In the book instance Book$0 Name$1 is related to Addr$0,
but in the book instance Book$1  the same Name$1 is related to Addr$1.

In terms of the real-life address book, I can interpret such situation as unintended
modification of book entries.

If I apply suggestion from [Alloy book example is wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76167330/alloy-book-example-is-wrong) and add additional constraint **b != b"**, then the analysis results satisfy my expectations: existing entries are not changed after add.

How we can interpret the results of analysis for the original variant, and
why additional constraint b != b" was not used from the beginning ?

The model is exactly the same as in the Address Book Example:

```
module tour/addressBook1f ----- Page 12

sig Name, Addr { }

sig Book {
    addr: Name -> lone Addr
}

pred add [b, bn: Book, n: Name, a: Addr] {
   bn.addr = b.addr + n->a
}

pred showAdd [b, bm: Book, n: Name, a: Addr] {
   add [b, bm, n, a]
   #Name.(bm.addr) > 1
}

// This command generates an instance similar to Fig 2.5
run showAdd for 3 but 2 Book
```

Comment: This seems to be a question that should be asked from the author, and not us. As such, this seems to be an opinion-based question.

Comment: Please provide the exact models you used in order to be able to assess them and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that some results may appear different than in the book, without being wrong, for at least 3 reasons: a code change in Alloy that modified the order of some operations, symmetry breaking, and using this or that SAT solver as a backend (for instance, I don't get the same instance as you when using Glucose41). But, if you keep pressing `New` until exhaustion, you shall walk along all possible non-symmetric instances.

Now your issue isn't what you think. If, in your instance, you consider the value of `$showAdd_b` and `$showAdd_bm`, which are the values given to `b` and `bm` in *this* instance, you'll see that they both correspond to `Book$1`. The instance you get is in fact correct but a bit peculiar: it shows that if `Book$1` contains entries `Name$0->Addr$0` and `Name$1->Addr$1`, then after adding `Name$1->Addr$1` (the value for `$showAdd_n` and `$showAdd_a`), it still contains the same entries. Said otherwise, `Book$0` *doesn't play any role in this instance*.

Now if you add the constraint that `b != bm`, then Alloy will find another instance, more as you expected.

As to why the additional constraint was not used from the beginning, I'd say that it usually considered good if your specification is not too strong because it allows more instances (= it covers more situations). And here, the instance found is indeed an acceptable situation: it shows a situation where one wants to add some entry to an address book, but as it's already here, the address book is unchanged. The tricky part was that you thought that `Book$0` was involved while it wasn't.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, now it is clear !